Interpreting Kolmogorov–Arnold representation theorem and separability
I recently came across an article proposing Kolmogorov-Arnold Networks as an efficient replacement for the traditional multi-layer perceptrons used in feed-forward neural networks, and so wanted to look into the Kolmogorov-Arnold Representation Theorem on which the approach is based.  That theorem states that any multivariate continuous function can be represented as a superposition of one-dimensional functions, i.e.,
$$f(\mathbf{X}) = f(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum_{q=0}^{2n} \Psi_q \bigg (\sum_{p=1}^{n} \psi_{q,p} (x_p) \bigg )$$
The Wikipedia article on the topic claims that

In a sense, [Kolmogorov and Arnold] showed that the only true multivariate function is the sum, since every other function can be written using univariate functions and summing.

This interpretation is based on the article On Nonlinear Functions of Linear Combinations, page 180, where it is stated that

In modern notation, Hilbert asked if there are genuine multivariate functions.  Of course, $x+y$ is a function of two variables but $xy = e^{ln(x) + ln(y)}$ is a superposition of univariate functions and $+$.  Kolmogorov and Arnold showed that, in this sense, $+$ is the only function of two variables.

By this they mean that, for example, if $f(x,y) = x y$, then we can re-express this in terms of sums of univariate functions: $f(x,y) = x y = e^{ln(x) + ln(y)}$.  Likewise, $f(x,y,z) = x^{y/z} = e^{e^{ln(y) + ln(ln(x)) - log(z)}}$.
This got me thinking about separable preferences in economics, which state arise when one may write the utility function as
$$U(x_1,...x_n) = u_1(x_1) + ... + u_n(x_n)$$
It is usually taught that maximizing $U(\mathbf{X})$ is the same as maximizing $g(U(\mathbf{X}))$ insofar as $g()$ is a monotone transformation, but monotonicity doesn't appear to be necessary.  For example, this post argues that as long as the optimum isn't on the boundary that a monotonic transformation isn't required.  The answer there states that

objective function is $f(x)$ and a transformation is made to the variable/s $x=g(y)$.
$$\frac {df(g(y))}{dy}=f^{'}(x)g^{'}(y)$$ $$\frac {d^2f(g(y))}{dy^2}=f^{''}(x)(g^{'})^2+f^{'}g^{''}(y)$$ at the optimal point $x_0$ $$f^{'}(x_0)=0$$ therefore,
$$\frac {d^2f(g(y))}{dy^2}=f^{''}(x)(g^{'})^2$$
So if it the minimum/maximum of f, it should be min/max of $f(g(y))$. At this time, both functions are assumed to be derivative.

This seems to hint to me that, after an appropriate transformation, the utility function should be rendered additively separable.  But this isn't right.  Can someone point to my mistake?
